# Disable Windows Corner Snap (2x2 vertical resizing)

Tags: windows-10, aero-snap

**update:** The 2x2 snapping is called ["Corner Snap"](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/06/04/arrange-your-windows-in-a-snap/). There are two features that make Corner Snap more useful:

- ["Snap Fill"](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/06/04/arrange-your-windows-in-a-snap/)
- [Side-by-side windows resize](http://windows.wonderhowto.com/how-to/snap-resize-side-by-side-windows-windows-10-0165358/)

Figuring out how to use these features made me reconsider the desire to disable Corner Snap, so other  users might find this useful, too.

---

<kbd>WIN</kbd>-<kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>WIN</kbd>-<kbd>DOWN</kbd> are two keyboard shortcuts I use very frequently. However, I wish they behaved like they did before Microsoft introduced 2x2 Snap in Windows 10. I switch between maximized, minimized, and half-screen quite often. However, I almost never use the intermediate 2x2 snapping states. (Here's [more info](http://www.howtogeek.com/198230/how-to-use-snap-assist-and-2x2-snap-on-windows-10/) about Windows Snap.)

**Is there a way to disable the intermediate 2x2 snapping states?** I would like to keep the other snapping behavior. Ideally, the 2x2 snapping would only be activated with a modifier key like <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>WIN</kbd>-<kbd>UP</kbd>.

This registry key might be related, but I could not find any documentation for it:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\SnapSizing`

Comment: The minimize shortcut I use to get around this problem is alt+space (release keys) then press "M". You can do this fairly quickly, and doesn't introduce those problems

Answer (score 2):

Consider AutoHotKey as an option.

Just create a .ahk script and put it in the autostart. Something like this should work:

```
#Up::WinMaximize, A
```

`#` is win modifier, `Up` is name of a key to hook, and stuff after `::` runs on keypress. `WinMaximize` is a function. `A` is a parameter which stands for active window.

You can do a lot of easy productivity hacks with AutoHotKey, and it is free and open source.

A quick Google search pointed me to [this AutoHotKey Script](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/16755-help-toggle-maximizerestore-with-same-hotkey/). To make Win+Down restore maximized windows and minimize normal windows you need to add this:

```
#Down::
    WinGet MX, MinMax, A
    If MX
        WinRestore A
    Else WinMaximize A
```